# How can I make this userform timer faster?

Tags: performance, vba, excel, timer

I have a userform that displays a goal time for workers to shoot for when completing a task. It also has a stopwatch on it that is controlled by a start, stop, and reset button on the userform. If the stopwatch time reaches the goal time and goes over, then there is a box called "extra time" that starts counting up. It just displays how much extra time the employees are taking to complete a task. The code runs insanely slow, and I think it's just because it is continuously runs a do until statement.

Is there anything I could do to make Excel not freeze up as much when I run this?

```
Dim StopTimer As Boolean
Dim Etime As Single
Dim Etime0 As Single
Dim LastEtime As Single
Dim goal As Single
Dim Etime1 As Single
Dim Etime2 As Single
Dim LastEtime2 As Single

Public Sub btnReset_Click()
StopTimer = True
Etime = 0
Etime0 = 0
LastEtime = 0
Etime1 = 0
Etime2 = 0
LastEtime2 = 0
lblTime.Caption = "00:00:00"
lblExtra.Caption = "00:00:00"
End Sub

Public Sub btnStart_Click()
goal = 86400 * (Sheets("Input").Range("C2"))    'goal time in seconds
StopTimer = False
Etime0 = Timer()
Etime1 = Timer() + goal
Do Until StopTimer

If Etime < goal Then
    Etime = Int((Timer() - Etime0) * 100) / 100
    If Etime > LastEtime Then
        LastEtime = Etime
        lblTime.Caption = Format(Etime / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
        DoEvents
    End If
Else
    Etime2 = Int((Timer() - Etime1) * 100) / 100
    If Etime2 > LastEtime2 Then
        LastEtime2 = Etime2
        lblExtra.Caption = Format(Etime2 / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
        DoEvents
    End If
End If

Loop
End Sub

Public Sub btnStop_Click()
StopTimer = True
End Sub

Public Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim cotime As Single
'Dim lookup As String
'lookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.c
'cotime = application.WorksheetFunction.IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Combobox1&Combobox2,AvgFor12to14,2,FALSE)),"N/A",VLOOKUP(Combobox1&Combobox2,AvgFor12to14,2,FALSE)/1440))

Sheets("Input").Range("A2") = Me.ComboBox1.Value
'Me.AvgTime.Value = Format(cotime, "hh:mm:ss")
Me.AvgTime.Caption = Format(Sheets("Input").Range("C2"), "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub

Public Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Sheets("Input").Range("B2") = Me.ComboBox2.Value
Me.AvgTime.Caption = Format(Sheets("Input").Range("C2"), "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Application.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox2 = ""
ComboBox1 = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to be clear, is this code is written in a .bas code module, or it's a sheet's code-behind?

Comment: This is in the userform module

Comment: I was looking at this a little closer today, can you explain exactly why you're casting to an int and multiplying... well, why are you doing this? `Etime = Int((Timer() - Etime0) * 100) / 100` It doesn't seem to do anything except randomly skew the value by a hundredth of a second or so.

Answer (score 8):

Just formatting first:

Your code is missing indentation and has some extra newlines in it.

Your `Do Until` loop should be double indented because it is inside of a sub.
You should also get rid of the extraneous commented code. If you got it working, get rid of the junk.

Here is what the code should look like:

```
Dim StopTimer As Boolean
Dim Etime As Single
Dim Etime0 As Single
Dim LastEtime As Single
Dim goal As Single
Dim Etime1 As Single
Dim Etime2 As Single
Dim LastEtime2 As Single

Public Sub btnReset_Click()
    StopTimer = True
    Etime = 0
    Etime0 = 0
    LastEtime = 0
    Etime1 = 0
    Etime2 = 0
    LastEtime2 = 0
    lblTime.Caption = "00:00:00"
    lblExtra.Caption = "00:00:00"
End Sub

Public Sub btnStart_Click()
    goal = 86400 * (Sheets("Input").Range("C2"))    'goal time in seconds
    StopTimer = False
    Etime0 = Timer()
    Etime1 = Timer() + goal
    Do Until StopTimer
        If Etime < goal Then
            Etime = Int((Timer() - Etime0) * 100) / 100
            If Etime > LastEtime Then
                LastEtime = Etime
                lblTime.Caption = Format(Etime / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
                DoEvents
            End If
        Else
            Etime2 = Int((Timer() - Etime1) * 100) / 100
            If Etime2 > LastEtime2 Then
                LastEtime2 = Etime2
                lblExtra.Caption = Format(Etime2 / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
                DoEvents
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Public Sub btnStop_Click()
    StopTimer = True
End Sub

Public Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim cotime As Single
    Sheets("Input").Range("A2") = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Me.AvgTime.Caption = Format(Sheets("Input").Range("C2"), "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub

Public Sub ComboBox2_Change()   
    Sheets("Input").Range("B2") = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    Me.AvgTime.Caption = Format(Sheets("Input").Range("C2"), "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox2 = ""
    ComboBox1 = ""
End Sub
```

It is a lot easier to read this way as well.

---

Your naming should be "pascalCase" for everything.

Lose the [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) on the labels; name the labels appropriately, like `timeOutput` or something like that.

- `StopTimer` -> `stopTimer`
- `Etime` -> `eTime`
- `LastEtime` -> `lastETime`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how to make this perform better, but there are a couple of nit-picky things I can share.

- `86400` is a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). It would be better to declare a constant with a meaningful name like `Private Const SecondsInADay as Int = 86400`. It took me a few minutes and a calculator to figure out what it was.
- This block of code is an almost exact duplicate and should become it's own

  ```
  If Etime < goal Then
      Etime = Int((Timer() - Etime0) * 100) / 100
      If Etime > LastEtime Then
          LastEtime = Etime
          lblTime.Caption = Format(Etime / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
          DoEvents
      End If
  Else
      Etime2 = Int((Timer() - Etime1) * 100) / 100
      If Etime2 > LastEtime2 Then
          LastEtime2 = Etime2
          lblExtra.Caption = Format(Etime2 / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
          DoEvents
      End If
  End If
  ```

To get started, you could define the two functions below.

```
Private function getTimeAsInt(ByVal timeAsSingle as Single)
    getTimeAsInt = Int((Timer() - timeAsSingle) * 100) / 100
End Sub

Private Function formatTime(ByVal timeAsSingle as Single)
    formatTime = Format(timeAsSingle / SecondsInADay, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

This reduces the duplication a little bit, but not a whole lot.

```
Do Until StopTimer
    If Etime < goal Then
        Etime = getTimeAsInt(Etime0)
        If Etime > LastEtime Then
            LastEtime = Etime
            lblTime.Caption = formatTime(Etime)
            DoEvents
        End If
    Else
        Etime2 = getTimeAsInt(Etime1)
        If Etime2 > LastEtime2 Then
            LastEtime2 = Etime2
            lblExtra.Caption = formatTime(Etime2)
            DoEvents
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: I suspect an OOP approach might allow you to abstract away all of this duplication though. Unfortunately, I don't have the time right now to figure that all out.